# Scrapy How to scrape HTTPS site through SSL proxy

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, scrapy

I've SSL proxy server and I want to **scrape** https site. I mean the connection between scrapy and the proxy is encrypted then the proxy will open a connection to the website.
after some debugging I found the following:-
currently scrapy handle the situation as follows:-

if the site is http it use ScrapyProxyAgent which send client hello then send a connect request for the website to the proxy

but if the site is https

it use a TunnelingAgent which does not send client hello to the proxy and hence the connection is terminated.

What I need is to tell scrapy to first establish a connection via ScrapyProxyAgent then use a TunnelingAgent not sure how to do that.

I tried to create a https DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS but I'm not that expert

```
class MyHTTPDownloader(HTTP11DownloadHandler):

    def download_request(self, request, spider):
        """Return a deferred for the HTTP download"""

        timeout = request.meta.get('download_timeout') or self._connectTimeout
        bindaddress = request.meta.get('bindaddress')
        proxy = request.meta.get('proxy')
        agent = ScrapyProxyAgent(reactor,proxyURI=to_bytes(proxy, encoding='ascii'),
                    connectTimeout=timeout, bindAddress=bindaddress, pool=self._pool)
        _, _, proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyParams = _parse(proxy)
        proxyHost = to_unicode(proxyHost)
        url = urldefrag(request.url)[0]
        method = to_bytes(request.method)
        headers = TxHeaders(request.headers)
        omitConnectTunnel = b'noconnect' in proxyParams
        proxyConf = (proxyHost, proxyPort,
                     request.headers.get(b'Proxy-Authorization', None))
        if request.body:
            bodyproducer = _RequestBodyProducer(request.body)
        if request.body:
            bodyproducer = _RequestBodyProducer(request.body)
        elif method == b'POST':
            bodyproducer = _RequestBodyProducer(b'')
        else:
            bodyproducer = None
            start_time = time()
        tunnelingAgent = TunnelingAgent(reactor, proxyConf,
                             contextFactory=self._contextFactory, connectTimeout=timeout,
                             bindAddress=bindaddress, pool=self._pool)

        agent.request(method, to_bytes(url, encoding='ascii'), headers, bodyproducer)
```

I need to establish a tunnel after the proxy agent is connected.
is that even possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: *"which does not send client hello to the proxy"* - this is perfectly normal. Proxying HTTPS is done by connecting to the proxy in plain, sending a CONNECT request and getting a response and then speaking HTTPS (HTTP over TLS) only through this established tunnel. __There is no TLS with the proxy involved__ but only with the server. I'm not sure what kind of proxy you are using but it might not be a proper HTTP proxy as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much Steffen for your comment, I'm talking about end to end encryption, i.e. connect over SSL to the proxy then to open a tunnel for the HTTPS server. I can do that with curl for instance if I issue curl -x https://proxy:port -v https://website it works, it connect to the proxy over ssl then connect to the server

Comment: `curl -x proxy:port` does exactly what I say: connect plain to the proxy to create a tunnel and then do end-to-end SSL with the server by using this tunnel. There is no SSL spoken with the proxy as endpoint, i.e. all SSL traffic is simply forwarded by the proxy to the server. The connection between the client and the proxy is not encrypted but the connection between client and server via proxy is.

Comment: sorry I meant curl -x https ://proxy:port -v https ://website when I type https+site it does not show in here

Comment: Sure, but the relevant part is `-x proxy:port` which behaves exactly like I said: *"The connection between the client and the proxy is not encrypted but the connection between client and server via proxy is."*